# Here Mobile SDK MapOffScreenRenderer performance problems

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here Mobile Android SDK and MapOffScreenRenderer class, for mirroring map view to presentation screen on android. But, unfortunately, performance of MapOffScreenRenderer generating bitmaps is not enough. What can I do about it?

Can I change RGB config of generated Bitmaps to increase performance? (switch it to rgb 565, for example, somehow).

Or can I change some settings to increase performance other ways?

Or maybe I can somehow get OpenGL texture without wrapping it into the Bitmap?

Is there any api to decide what layers of the map view I want to see at the bitmaps?

I'm using code from the [official documentation](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoffscreenrenderer.html). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the bitmaps captured by the offscreen renderer will always be super slow. It has to do a back buffer read from the rendering thread backed by a PBuffer surface. So no amount of RGB config can speed it up :)

If you know how to directly handle OpenGL calls, registering for an [OnMapRenderListener](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-onmaprenderlistener.html#topic-apiref) and [SurfaceUpdatedListener](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-offscreenrenderer-surfaceupdatedlistener.html#topic-apiref) to the MapOffScreenRenderer and using [MapOffScreenRenderer#start(SurfaceHolder, SurfaceUpdatedListener)](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoffscreenrenderer.html#topic-apiref__start-surfaceholder-offscreenrenderer-surfaceupdatedlistener) you can build exactly as you described for your use case. The SurfaceHolder allows the developer to supply a custom Android [surface](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoffscreenrenderer.html#topic-apiref__start-surfaceholder-offscreenrenderer-surfaceupdatedlistener) that the map will be rendered into. The SurfaceUpdatedListener provides the callback when the OpenGL rendering calls are commited via swapbuffers. See more advanced android documentation on [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) and [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#Surface%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29).

You can also try to render fewer layers using the [Map#setVisibleLayersAPI](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__setvisiblelayers-enumset-boolean) to turn off a few rendering layers. However, I doubt that would dramatically improve performance.

Your next reply is likely you would like a sample, but unfortunately I do not have anything publicly that I can share.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any kind of support who can help with code samples ?)

Comment: Or maybe some other advices or links?)

Comment: Finally made a workable POC. It works, if you transfer Surface from one app to another via AIDL and so OffScreenRenderer starts rendering to SurfaceView inside another app =) I think performance probably can't be better than at this case, right?

Comment: Congrats, yes that is probably the most optimal solution. Sorry we really need to improve on samples. This one is one of the more advanced parts of the SDK.